# mysql select based on one known field

Tags: mysql

The only known variable is Item (in this case Car)

I want to run a query where it shows all rows that have the same color as the Item i know.

Eg.. I want to run the query for car.

SELECT * from TABLE WHERE (Item color matches Car's color)

```
ITEM             COLOR
Car              Blue
House            Red
Boat             Green
Jetski           Red
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

```
select * from table where color = (select color from table where item = 'Car');
```

Comment: dont u want a from table clause in your inner query? ;o

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where color In (select color from table where item = 'Car');
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
select table.*
from table inner join table table_1 using (COLOR)
where table_1.ITEM = 'Car';
```

Comment: if Car is present more than once, it matches each color of Car